# Cppcheck internal error using addon findcasts.py

Tags: c, cppcheck

I am currently using Cppcheck version 2.12.0 for a research project. I am interested in working with the addons provided and attempted to use the findcasts.py addon to analyze a short .c file. I used the following command:

`cppcheck --addon=findcasts.py typeCast.c --addon-python=C:\\Users...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe --dump`

And received the following error:

> typeCast.c:0:0: error: Bailing out from analysis: Checking file failed: Failed to execute addon 'findcasts' (command: 'C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe  "C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\addons\findcasts.py" --cli typeCast.c.dump').
>
> Exitcode is nonzero. [internalError]

Other addons have functioned normally so the source of this particular error is unclear to me.

I have looked through the produced .dump file but did not find anything that explained the error. I am using the command line interface since my GUI is not recognizing the addons.

Comment: Could it be an incompatibility in the Python version? Say: did you check prerequisites for that plugin?

Comment: The plugin requires python 3, cppcheck requires at least python 1.8

Comment: If you add the `--verbose` flag you should get a more detailed error message.

Also the addon is not well maintained so it might not be working in all cases.